# Spring dynamic url access to css/js files

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a simple Spring boot application. There URL that would be used here is going to be like:

```
sub.domain.com/variable1/variable2
```

and variable1 and variable2 can be anything for example:

```
sub.domain.com/kfc/foo
sub.domain.com/subway/boo
```

and I capture those in my controller as below:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/{var1}/{var2}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String Index(@PathVariable(value="var1") String variable1, @PathVariable(value="var2") String variable2) {
        return "/index.html";
    }
}
```

which will redirect to my html page which is located at `src/main/webapp/index.html`

so the index page is loaded under the dynamic url but then none of the scrips or stylesheets are found because it's trying to find them under variable1 path.

for example if I have

```
sub.domain.com/kfc/foo
```

and my link to css in the index.html is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css" />
```

it will try to find the index.css under

```
sub.domain.com/kfc/styles/index.css
```

how can I tell the app to look into the right place for the styles or js files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index.html is trying to load styles from a relative path.

In order for index.html to load styles under sub.domain.com/styles/index.css, add a `/` in link tag **/**styles/index.css `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/index.css" />`

Comment: I felt the same thing of my self once :)